# Kotlin canonical way to initialize two or more vals by some conditions

Tags: kotlin

What is the canonical way of initializing two (or more) vals by condition?

```
var a : Int;// I want this to be val, not var
var b: Int;// I want this to be val, not var too

if(condition) {
 a = 1
 b = 2
} else {
 a = 3
 b = 4
}
```

Using "if" several times is not convenient, as there could be lots of vars and lots of conditions

```
val a = if(condition) 1 else 2
val b = if(condition) 3 else 4
```

Comment: Is it impossible to declare `val` at first case? If `a` and `b` are not fields, you can use `val`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using tuples and destructuring is nice and concise, you *can* just use `val` instead of `var` in the question's code!

(I tried it, and it works fine for me in IDEA with Kotlin 1.3.10.)

In Java, each of those would be called a 'blank final'; I don't know if Kotlin uses the same term.  In any case, as long as the compiler can see that such a variable always gets initialised exactly once (which they do here), it's happy.

Comment: If you paste the code into an empty file you get multiple errors. Also if it is in a class. You have to define a constructor or init-block for the if-statement

Comment: @leonardkraemer: As I said, it works for me.  If you paste the question's code into an empty file, it won't compile, as the `if` needs to be in a function, and `condition` isn't defined!  But if you do that, e.g. by adding `fun a(condition: Boolean) {` at the start and `}` at the end, then it compiles fine for me, either with `val` or with `var`.

Comment: @gidds, OMG, that's a surprise. I thought that vals should be always initialized with definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using Pair destructuring:

```
val (a, b) = if (condition) 1 to 2 else 3 to 4
```

You can read more in the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations

For 3 variables you can use `Triple`:

```
val (a, b, c) = if (condition) Triple(1, 2, 3) else Triple(3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: I was about to post this exact way, but then I realized that it wouldn't be this simple with 3+ variables. Anyway, with 2, this is fine.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng You can use `Triple` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/index.html) for 3 variables. Not sure about 4+

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) for this purpose.

```
val (a, b, c) = if (condition) listOf(1, 2, 3) else listOf(4, 5, 6)
```

For different types you can combine it with object creation:

```
data class ValueInitializer(
    val a: Int,
    val b: String
)

val (a: Int, b: String) = if (condition) 
         ValueInitializer(1, "String") 
    else 
         ValueInitializer(2, "String2")
```

Another point is that you can use `val` instead of `var` in your first example if `a` and `b` are local variables. For class fields you can initialize them inside `init` block, or mark them with `lateinit` modifier.

Comment: But what if a, b, c are of different types?

Comment: It's okay to use like this `val (a, b) = if (condition) listOf(1, "String1") else listOf(4, "String2")`

Comment: then a is Any and b is Any, not Int and String

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize in the `init`-block (or the constructor) you can use `val` which looks very clean and uses only one `if`:

```
class foo(){
    val a : Int
    val b : Int

    init{
        if(condition) {
            a = 1
            b = 2
        } else {
            a = 3
            b = 4
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise I would advise to read the initialisation from a config file, if there are many variables. In the spirit of decoupling code and data.